# Conditional expectation $E(\xi^2\mid\xi\eta)$ where $\xi, \eta$ iid $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Suppose $\xi, \eta \sim N(0,1)$ are two independent random variables. Then how can we calculate the composite conditional expectation $E(\xi^2\mid\xi\eta)$? I thought about calculating the distribution/density function of random vector $(\xi^2, \xi\eta)$ but the mapping is not bijective.

Comment: Let $U = \xi, V = \xi \eta.$ Instead of finding the joint distribution of $(U^2, UV),$ find the joint distribution of $(U,V)$ and then apply LOTUS: $\mathbb{E}[U^2 | V] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} u^2 p(u \ | v) du .$

Comment: Doing that calculation appears to give me a result of $ \frac{ |V| K_1( |V|) }{K_0(|V|)}$ where $K_n$ are modified Bessel functions of the second kind, arising due to integrals such as $\int^{\infty}_0 u \exp(-(u^2+v^2/u^2)/2) du$ and $\int^{\infty}_0 u^{-1} \exp(-(u^2+v^2/u^2)/2) du.$

Comment: @RagibZaman I arrived at similar integrals, but this is one of my course's homework and I wonder if such special functions should appear...

Comment: I was also surprised to seeing special functions appearing for what I guessed was a standard homework problem, but it appears this is just a case where such functions are necessary (I think your course would only expect you to leave the answer expressed in terms of the integrals). It appears $K_n$ occurs naturally when working with the product of independent $N(0,1)$ variables, e.g. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Independent_central-normal_distributions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Ragib's hint, the joint distribution of $U,V$ is $p(u,v)=\frac{1}{|u|}e^{\frac{u^2+\frac{v^2}{u^2}}{2}}$, $u\not =0$. Therefore by symmetry $E(U^2\mid V=v)=\frac{\int_0^{\infty}u^2p(u,v)du}{\int_0^{\infty}p(u,v)du}=\frac{|v| K_1(|v|)}{K_0(|v|)}$, $K_{\nu}$ Macdonald.